# SQL: How to only apply where to certain fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to apply a `where` clause to my `count` selects but not to the names, room code, or date.

Here is my query currently which applies the `where` to the whole statement:

```
SELECT
  l.name AS room_name,
  l.room_code,
  COUNT(res.*) AS nofixeditems,
  COUNT(m.*) AS noinmaintenance,
  rc.actiondate AS last_checked,
  concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.surname) AS checked_by
FROM
  resources res
  FULL JOIN room_checklist rc ON (rc.assetid = res.aid)
  FULL JOIN users u ON (u.uid = rc.actionuserid)
  FULL JOIN locations l ON (l.locationid = rc.locationid)
  FULL JOIN resource_locations rl ON (rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid)
  FULL JOIN maintenance.maintenance_log m ON (res.aid = m.asset_id)
WHERE
  res.archived IS NOT TRUE AND 
  rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid::bigint AND 
  res.hide_from_room_checklist IS NOT TRUE
GROUP BY
  l.name,
  l.room_code,
  rc.actiondate,
  checked_by
```

I need it to display the whole list of room names, codes, etc while displaying null on the counts where the data isnt available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean set condition for calculating in aggregation function you can use `filter (where conditions...)`

[Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

```sql
SELECT
  l.name AS room_name,
  l.room_code,
  COUNT(res.*) FILTER (WHERE ...) AS nofixeditems,
  COUNT(m.*) FILTER (WHERE ...) AS noinmaintenance,
  rc.actiondate AS last_checked,
  concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.surname) AS checked_by
FROM
  resources res
  FULL JOIN room_checklist rc ON (rc.assetid = res.aid)
  FULL JOIN users u ON (u.uid = rc.actionuserid)
  FULL JOIN locations l ON (l.locationid = rc.locationid)
  FULL JOIN resource_locations rl ON (rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid)
  FULL JOIN maintenance.maintenance_log m ON (res.aid = m.asset_id)
WHERE
  res.archived IS NOT TRUE AND 
  rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid::bigint AND 
  res.hide_from_room_checklist IS NOT TRUE
GROUP BY
  l.name,
  l.room_code,
  rc.actiondate,
  checked_by
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the subQuery

```
SELECT
  l.name AS room_name,
  l.room_code,
  (Select COUNT(*) from resources where ID = res.id AND ..) AS nofixeditems,
  (Select COUNT(*) from maintenance.maintenance_log where ID = m.id AND ..) AS noinmaintenance,
  rc.actiondate AS last_checked,
  concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.surname) AS checked_by
FROM
  resources res
  FULL JOIN room_checklist rc ON (rc.assetid = res.aid)
  FULL JOIN users u ON (u.uid = rc.actionuserid)
  FULL JOIN locations l ON (l.locationid = rc.locationid)
  FULL JOIN resource_locations rl ON (rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid)
  FULL JOIN maintenance.maintenance_log m ON (res.aid = m.asset_id)
WHERE
  res.archived IS NOT TRUE AND 
  rl.location_id_fixed = l.locationid::bigint AND 
  res.hide_from_room_checklist IS NOT TRUE
GROUP BY
  l.name,
  l.room_code,
  rc.actiondate,
  checked_by
```